# Unit tests with designated AppDelegate crashes on XCode 7

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ios8, appdelegate, xcode7-beta6

My unit test target crashes on Xcode 7.

I perform unit tests on my project with a designated app delegate class, different from my regular app delegate . The `UnitTestAppDelegate` is not a member of the app target, only of the test target.

In Xcode 6 it is working, the correct delegate is used, But in Xcode 7 (beta 6) the app crashes when trying to load to test delegate. I test using simulators, both iOS 8 and 9.

The file is not known to the app target:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unable to instantiate the UIApplication delegate instance. No class named UnitTestAppDelegate is loaded.'
```

My `main.m` file looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int returnValue;   

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        if (NSClassFromString(@"XCTest") != nil)
        {
            //use the test delegate
            returnValue = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"UnitTestAppDelegate");
        }
        else
        {
            //use the normal delegate
            returnValue = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
        }
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

I'm also attaching a screen shot of how my scheme is configured (the run and test are in the same scheme, although I also tried separating them).

[image]

Adding my `UnitTestAppDelegate` as a member of the app target fixes the crash, but I obviously don't want to add the file to my app.

Anyone else encountered this?

Any ideas?

Comment: I created a small demo project if anyone wants to try and figure it out.
https://github.com/ashavit/UnitTests-Different-AppDelegate

Answer (score 0):

See this related comment about the same issue as seen in Xcode 7 beta 6: http://qualitycoding.org/app-delegate-for-tests/#comment-63240

Comment: Thanx. I filed a radar too before seeing this.